# User model acting strange, works in rails console, saying undefined method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing this:

```
user = User.find( params[:id] )
```

when I do:

```
user.section_id
```

it says:

```
nomethoderror exception undefined method 'section_id' for <#Array:0x.....>
```

Why does it say <#Array?

In rails console, everything works fine when I do: `u = User.find(2)`

**Update**

My javascript is doing this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/user/add_section",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { id: id, section_text: sectionText
            },
            success: function(payload) {

            },
            error: function(jqx, ts, et) {

            },
            complete: function(){}
        });
```

Using chrome I can see that the id is 8.

My controller action:

```
def add_section

  user = User.find(params[:id])

  section_id = user.section_id   # error!!

end
```

I put a debugger in this code, and the object does load properly, it just that it loads into an array so this works:

```
user[0].section_id
```

**but in irb it works fine with:  user.section_id for the exact same value passed to the find method.**

Comment: What is in params[:id] ?

Comment: I am posting a integer id=8 for example.

Comment: Something with the error being `sectionid` and the method `section_id`?

Comment: @jakub no that was just a type by me, fixed.

Comment: chrome shows that my header form data is: id%5B%5D:8   not sure why it isn't id:8 ??

Comment: I asked question under my answer. I can help you if you provide me answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user = User.find( params[:id] )
```

Looks like `params[:id]` return an **Array**, so `user` - is an Array of users actually. Or it can be just one id wrap into `[]` like: `user = User.find [8]` - which will still return an Array with one element

So you should debug your `params[:id]`.

**UPD**

Also here is a problem in your application. It is not REST. You should call `/user/:id/add_section` path instead of `/user/add_section`.

Your routes:

```
resources :users do
  post :add_section, :on => :member
end
```

Comment: thanks for the rest tip, what would my route.rb look like with this then?  right now it is:  post 'add_section'

Comment: I've updated my answer. But what about your magical `params[:id]`? Did you fixed it ot just debugged?

Comment: well now I am getting the id from the url, so not passing it anymore.  still no idea why it was becoming an array!

Answer (score 0):

User.[find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) can return multiple types. You are not passing correct argument for your example. You can see parameters send to controller in server log or just print it via `p params`

Comment: I don't know where you got that. But it means id[]:8. So probably you are passing array with one element - 8. And when you pass array to find method it returns array also.

Comment: How are you calling this page ? What URL ? How are you building your link to this page ? Via some link_to ? What arguments are you passing there ?

Comment: Your update doesn't really answer the question. It shows that you're sending `id: id` in the Ajax call, but it doesn't show how you get the `id` variable assigned in the first place.