# Adding a restful route like: /users/234/add_section

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already have:

resources :users

How can I add a route (for POST only) that will work like:

/users/2343/add_section

Is it possible to add this route inside of the resources users block?

```
resources :users do

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      post 'add_section'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Having `add_section` there is not very RESTful. Consider having a subresource `section` and doing POST "/users/123/sections/"

Comment: Sometimes you can be not RESTful, but you should follow conventions always. As far as nobody knows what is going on in this action it should be at least a member route, and at most as a subresource, I think :)

Answer (score 1):

As I answered on your [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771637/user-model-acting-strange-works-in-rails-console-saying-undefined-method-in-con/5773153#5773153)

```
resources :users do
  post :add_section, :on => :member
end
```